# Magento 2 create the Inventory source programmatically

Tags: magento2, multi-source-inventory, stock-availability, magento2-b2b

I am new to Magento 2 Can anyone help me with how to programmatically create the Inventory source? What is the use of the stock channel?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an inventory source via an `UpgradeData.php` script, I'm not sure how familiar you are with upgrade scripts, but there's plenty of documentation and tutorials around that, so I'll just list the upgrade script part.

```
namespace VENDOR\MODULE_NAME\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ResourceConnection
     */
    private $resource;

    /**
     * UpgradeData constructor.
     * @param ResourceConnection $resource
     */
    public function __construct(
        ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
        $this->resource = $resource;
    }

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
        $connection = $this->resource->getConnection();
        $sourceData = [
            SourceInterface::SOURCE_CODE => 'ABCD',
            SourceInterface::NAME => 'My New Source',
            SourceInterface::ENABLED => 1,
            SourceInterface::DESCRIPTION => 'My New Source Description',
            SourceInterface::LATITUDE => 41.227791,
            SourceInterface::LONGITUDE => -39.927117,
            SourceInterface::COUNTRY_ID => 'GB',
            SourceInterface::POSTCODE => 'AB1 1AB',
        ];
        $connection->insert($this->resource->getTableName('inventory_source'), $sourceData);
    }

}
```

Then when you run a setup:upgrade, the upgrade script will add the source to your inventory sources.

Comment: But i need to create the source dynamically while customer account registration

Comment: @Jaisa I need to create a new inventory source programmatically but facing issues when using the above code. did you find the solution?

Comment: @Siva  Not yet. I need to create a source while saving a customer account.So I did not tried the above one

Comment: @Jaisa Ok. Hope you'll find the solution for your requirement